# How do I overwrite in a calculator?

Tags: c#, calculator

This is my code for the calculator written in SharpDevelop. I need to know how to overwrite a number.

In my code when I'm texting the first number and after i press the add button the textbox gets cleared.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
  public MainForm()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  double total1 = 0;
  double total2 = 0;

  void BtnOneClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnOne.Text;
  }

  void BtnTwoClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnTwo.Text;
  }

  ...

  void BtnZeroClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnZero.Text;           
  }

  void BtnClearClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    txtDisplay.Clear();
  }

  void BtnPlusClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    total1 += double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    txtDisplay.Clear();

    plusButtonClicked = true;
    minusButtonClicked = false;
    multiplyButtonClicked = false;
    divideButtonClicked = false;
  }

  ...

  bool plusButtonClicked = false;
  bool minusButtonClicked = false;
  bool multiplyButtonClicked = false;
  bool divideButtonClicked = false;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking... maybe you shouldn't call `txtDisplay.Clear()` in your `BtnPlusClick` method then?

Comment: Because `void BtnPlusClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        total1 += double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        txtDisplay.Clear();`

Comment: if i remove txtDisplay.Clear() the second number will be added next to the first

Comment: You will Clear textbox before adding second number.

Comment: Is there any chance that what you're looking for is `total1 = double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);` so that total1 now equals the number in the textbox rather than the previous total1 added to the number in the textbox?

Comment: none of this works. So I want that when I type for ex number 1 in the textbox and then press the + button to have the number 1 still displayed and after i type the second number to display the second number. Check the calculator from your computer to see what I'm talking about

Comment: Check my example edit2, is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: I agree with Chris...you need to spell out exactly what you are looking for. If you want help, you need to update your question to actually ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

i think you want

```
void BtnPlusClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
total1 += double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
txtDisplay.Text = total1.toString();
```

**Edit:** `.Clear` will remove the text from the text box.. I think if you wanted something else to happen then you need to rethink what you are trying to do

**Edit2** if this isnt what you wanted I dont know what is

```
    int total = 0;
    bool newNum = true;
    //1
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBox1.Text = newNum ? "1" : textBox1.Text + "1";
        newNum = false;
    }
    //Add
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newNum = true;
        total += int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.Clear();
    }
    //Equals
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = total.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's beacause of this line:
    txtDisplay.Clear();
in your method
    BtnPlusClick();

if you want to clear it only when you start to provide next number - just chceck your bool flags(plusButtonClicked, etc.) - if on of them is set to true - then make
    txtDisplay.Clear();